# Stack trace shown while merging tags

Tags: bug, status-completed

I created a new tag synonym and then decided that I should just merge the other tag with this. Apparently I cannot merge it because I already created the synonym. I guess that is fine, but instead of a nice error page I got a nasty stack trace.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will no longer get a stacktrace on this and several of our other code paths.

This is in the next build.